# Uncaught TypeError: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery. jQuery must be included before Bootstrap's JavaScript. at Object.jQueryDetection

Tags: next.js

I am using Next.js App and trying to add jquery in the application but the issue is sometimes it work sometimes not, I already added it to top of the script.

```
import React from 'react';
import Head from 'next/head'
import Script from 'next/script';
const LoadCss = () => {
    return ( <>
        
        <Head>
            
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
        </Head> 
    </>
    );
}

 
export default LoadCss;
```

---

```
import React from 'react';
import Script from 'next/script';
const LoadJs  = () => {
    return ( <>
<Script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></Script>
        
        <Script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></Script>
        <Script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></Script>
    </> );
}
 
export default LoadJs ;
```

and rest are loaded after this but still facing the issue.

I also try to load it via local folder but still no success.

Kinldy help

Comment: That code isn’t relevant to the *source* of the error because there is no loading of the Bootstrap **.js** file. Go find where the Bootstrap **.js** file is loaded and ensure that jQuery is loaded first.

Comment: Bootstrap is loading on footer

Comment: And apparently also done on pages that don’t “LoadCss”. Just put the jQuery as the first line of “LoadJs” so it is guaranteed to always be loaded before the Bootstrap js.

Comment: use you solution but still having the same issue @user2864740